# Is there a a way I can store information with Java without requiring a dedicated server?

Tags: java, database

By this, I simply mean that I want a program that stores its information locally in tables, on whatever computer it is running on, compared to needing to connect to a dedicated server to do so. I'd prefer if there was a way to do this in SQL language. I've tried looking up frameworks that do this, and haven't had any luck (maybe I'm not wording it right). I do know that this is possible anyway in the .NET framework with C#, so I assumed there was a way to do it with other languages as well.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking for

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/h2_database/h2_database_jdbc_connection.htm

Comment: Please [edit] and mention your solutios known in C# (frameworks, databases). Maybe you would better ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So essentially you are asking for a way to make your program manage a database by itself without relying on an external program to host a database even if it's on the same local computer? If so, I would go with Elliott's answer and use SQLite.

Comment: `stores... locally in tables...compared to needing to connect to a dedicated server` - what stops you from installing DBMS on the localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Embedded Database

If you want to use a database engine within your app locally rather than communications with an external database server, use an embedded database.

My first choice would be [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)). This pure Java product can be configured to run within your app, or can run as an external database server, or both.

You might also consider [Apache Derby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Derby), and SQLite.

For a specific recommendation, use the sister site: [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

## Local server

Another option is to install a database server on the same machine as your app. So no network is involved. Your Java app would make a JDBC connection to the server but would be communicating within the same OS rather than going out over the network. This is much faster and more reliable than involving a network.

This setup is common with web apps, where the [web container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) such as Apache Tomcat or Eclipse Jetty shares the same machine with a database server such as Postgres.

Monitor your deployments to be sure you are not overburdening the machine.